# How to find card reader block device?

Tags: dd, card-reader

I am trying to make an image from USB Card Reader using `dd`. When I connect device, this is what the log tells me:

```
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.579168] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=9260
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.579171] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.579173] usb 1-1: Product: CU8871 CFast Card Reader
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.579174] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: XXX
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.579175] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: A69AB1E1201103290001088909A38A292
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.659152] scsi host9: uas
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/usb1/1-1"
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.661589] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      CSS HSK72W002G   0123 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.669680] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.673337] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] 3863664 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.682743] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.682747] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.684793] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Aug 21 11:26:50 acid kernel: [ 1399.684796] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Aug 21 11:27:21 acid kernel: [ 1429.864084] sd 9:0:0:0: uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Aug 21 11:27:21 acid kernel: [ 1429.864088] sd 9:0:0:0: CDB: 
Aug 21 11:27:21 acid kernel: [ 1429.864089] Report supported operation codes: a3 0c 01 12 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
Aug 21 11:27:21 acid kernel: [ 1429.864107] scsi host9: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
Aug 21 11:27:21 acid kernel: [ 1430.132133] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
Aug 21 11:27:21 acid kernel: [ 1430.622732] scsi host9: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
```

However, I can't find anything with `sdb` in `/dev`. How to refer to this device as block device to make an image?

UPD: some more debug info

```
acid@acid:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for acid: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="7d39c5c7-28c5-41b5-b504-4d705380e7be" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="9ff9235f-3c91-4ace-851b-90a2ae868c6f" TYPE="swap"
```

and even more

```
acid@acid:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0451:9260 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

more

```
acid@acid:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0     8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     6G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

After few times connecting/disconnecting device I got the following error box

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/acid/3008F94408F90A1C: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/acid/3008F94408F90A1C"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read of MFT, mft=6 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
Failed to open inode FILE_Bitmap: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Comment: What does `sudo blkid` tell you? And `lsusb`? Please add the output to your question.

Comment: Try one more; `lsblk` and add it as above.

Comment: If it is working, and mounted, it should show up in the `mount` command, something like `/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/jos/9016-4EF8 type vfat`. If it is not mounted, there should be something in `dmesg | tail` that tells you why not. You can use the `dd` command on `/dev/mmcblk0p1`.

Comment: @Jos there is no `/dev/mm*` and nothing new in `/media`. Upon connection of device dmesg produces no logs, only syslog which I showed.

Comment: oh, errm so my answer is completly wrong.... can you post the sudo blkid output?

Comment: @Νίκος Φυτίλης please check my original post, I have given that output.

Comment: erm where is your device exactly ? all i can see is sda (which i one device) and its partitions (1,5) no mmc no sdb

Comment: `sda` is main hard drive. That's the problem, I don't see my device, which is supposed to be `sdb`. Check error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some new card readers are not currently supported by the kernel. You might need to use a later or even a rc version for your card reader to be listed (probably something like /dev/mmcblk0)

You can see in the dmesg that it is not properly supported and a uas_eh_bus_reset_handler is called. I am not an expert to kernel messages but it says that the usb is reset.

EDIT: The CFast Card Reader a usb 3.0 capable device? VirtualBox (v 5.0) only recently has updated to have usb 3.0 capabilities. Check your version

Comment: I wouldn't say it's new card reader. There is no mm* device

Comment: Nevertheless, the reset IS called so it is a very old kernel or a very wierd card reader. Btw, you are using linux in a vm, so the usb support is a bit fanky in Virtualbox. Try vmware. (what I use, not saying it is better or something :P )

Comment: It's Ubuntu 14. That's why I posted my question to solve this funkiness :)

Comment: is the CFast Card Reader a usb 3.0 capable device? VirtualBox (v 5.0) only resently has updated to have usb 3.0 capabilities. Check your version.

Comment: That's a good point. It is USB3.0 and VirtualBox is not very last. I will try to update and write back.

Comment: Latest VirtualBox, latest Guest additions, same result. `sudo blkid` doesn't show it.

Comment: It appears that after waiting about 15 minutes, something is happening. First time I have seen it mounted, second time I remounted it, it gaves me the error that it can't mount it. Could it be that some file system check is going on in background?

Comment: If you just what to make a backup, why don't you try from a livecd (usb)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use command `blockdev`

```
 sudo blockdev --report /dev/mmcblk0
```

But you can make `.img` without block size with command

```
 sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=~/path/USB_image.img bs=512 count=1
```

Comment: but there probably is not even an mmcblk0, if blkid is not listing the device, or  am I terribly wrong?

Comment: There is no `mmcblk0` entity.

Comment: @ΝίκοςΦυτίλης Oddly enough `blkid` does not list my USB card (only the fixed drives), but `sudo blkid` does.

Comment: Btw try what is suggested by the answer but with sdb instead of mmcblk0

Comment: There is no sdb. Some error message box appears, I've posted it in my original question.

Comment: Try this. Pool out card and do `ls /dev/`. Then put card and again do`ls /dev/`. Do you have anything different in this two outputs?